# Cannot save data in more than one array in Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I am trying to save data in Laravel which has multiple arrays.

The array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [client_personnel_name] => Ron
            [client_id] => 52
            [client_personnel_email] => abc@gmail.com
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [client_personnel_name] => John
            [client_id] => 52
            [client_personnel_email] => abc@gmail.com
        )

)
```

When I save this data:

```
$personnel = ClientsPersonnel::create($client_personnel);
$personnel->save();
```

On debugging what data is being created to insert. 
This is what I get in the attributes where the sent data is stored

```
[attributes:protected] => Array
        (
            [updated_at] => 2015-04-23 06:53:05
            [created_at] => 2015-04-23 06:53:05
            [id] => 2
        )
```

How can I save the data which has multiple arrays?

Comment: loop the array and save seperately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DB::insert()`, like this:

```
DB::table('client_personnel')->insert(array($client_personnel));
```

As an alternative, you could do this using loop like.

```
foreach ($personnels as $personnelAttributes) {
    $personnel = new ClientsPersonnel($personnelAttributes);
    $personnel->save();
}
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Laravel Eloquent does not have bulk update nor insert function. You need to create new ClientsPersonnel for each subarray and save it individually.

Answer (score 0):

Just loop the arrays and insert seperately:

```
foreach ($client_personnel as $client) {
    ClientsPersonnel::create($client);
}
```